# How to do operations on state constructor variables in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, state, setstate

I'd like to show change of wordCount in `homeWidget`

```
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ...
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: RecorderView(
              onSaved: _onRecordComplete,
              wordCount:wordCount,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

the variable`wordCount` relies on RecordView method:

I write this to get state variable here

```
class RecorderView extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function onSaved;
  final int wordCount;
  const RecorderView({Key key, @required this.onSaved,@required this.wordCount}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _RecorderViewState createState() => _RecorderViewState();
}

class _RecorderViewState extends State<RecorderView> {

//in one method
    widget.wordCount++;
}
```

I want to add wordCount here,but it says it's a final one.How could I inherit wordCount from homeWidget without `final`? I just want to change the word show in wordCount automatically,thanks!!

Comment: You would need to lift the state up or do a more advanced state management. Check out [InheritedWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html) for a flutter framework method, or something like provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant inherit the variable, you can however initialize it to a value from the widget.

```
class RecorderView extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function onSaved;
  final int wordCount;
  const RecorderView({Key key, @required this.onSaved,@required this.wordCount}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _RecorderViewState createState() => _RecorderViewState();
}

class _RecorderViewState extends State<RecorderView> {
int _wordCount;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
_wordCount = widget.wordCount;
}
}
```